# connection reset when upload file with size more than 1GB

Tags: php, apache, centos, cpanel, whm

I try to upload file to my own website when I try upload file with less than 1GB it's work fine, But when I try with large file give me message : "The connection was reset." [ERR_CONNECTION_RESET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MM7Yb.png)

Then I try to edit and increase all value php.ini

```
   php_value max_execution_time 10000
   php_value max_input_time 10000
   php_value max_input_vars 1000
   php_value memory_limit 2000M
   php_value post_max_size 2000M
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 10000
   php_value upload_max_filesize 2000M
```

In the end still have a problem

I work on my own server and I have access to whm, cpanel with centos 7
And there's no logs for this problem on apache logs

Comment: The default limit in Apache > 2.4.53 is 1GB (1073741824 bytes) - [LimitRequestBody](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody)

Comment: For a file of size larger than 1G, better use other method to upload (**consider this**: if you try sending an email with an attachment of size larger than 1G thru a normal ISP, what happens ?)

Comment: @nnichols I've just add `limitRequestBody 0` to htaccess file it's works fine thank you

Answer (score -1):

Can you check the features of the package you added on WHM? The quota of the package you have added may be low.

Comment: You don't have to create an answer to ask a simple question. Just a comment is enough :)